# Cycle Through Org Mode Todo Tags Based on Tag

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, todo, org-tags, tags

I have one org file, inbox.org, which I use for keeping all of my todos.  I have todos of several categories, like:

- work
- memory
- fitness
- outreach

and so on.

Is there a way to order these tags to define a cycle, which would promote the next todo item with whichever tag comes next in the cycle, to `A#` priority?

In other words, I want to be able to define somewhere `("work", "memory", "fitness", "article", ...)` and once I complete the next `"work"` item, it's moved to the back of the list, and now my next `"memory"` item (only one, preferably) is given `A#` priority.

Comment: So IIUC you have multiple items of each type: you are trying to impose an order on the types, but how are you imposing an order on the items of each type? In other words, in your example, how is the "next" memory item to be selected, out of all the items of type "memory"?

Comment: @NickD. The next "memory" would be whichever memory appears first in the org file and isn't marked DONE